# window.close() not working in Jquery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a dialogue box modal for  displaying terms and condition on my webpage. But at button disagree the webpage doesnot close while calling function **window.close**. 
 **I want to close the recent page after clicking the button disagree**

 Below pasted is the sample code I am having problem at.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:600,
      width:400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        'Agree': function() {
          $( this ).dialog( window.location.assign('../mdv/main.php') );
        },
        'Disagree': function() {
          $( this ).dialog( window.close() );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: what do you want to close, the dialog, or the whole page?

Comment: @paul I want to close the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:600,
      width:400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        'Agree': function() {
          $( this ).dialog( window.location.assign('../mdv/main.php') );
        },
        'Disagree': function() {
          $( this ).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

You can either close the dialog itself using the code above or you can close the window if it's a popup window opened previously via JavaScript.
In which case you'll need the reference of that to invoke the close method.

However you can't close an entire webpage/tab with JavaScript which is a javaScript limitation. As I mentioned, you can only close it if it was previously opened with JavaScript.

Comment: still makes no sense passing a window method as dialog argument in `Agree`.

Comment: @Nick I want to close the webpage instead of the dialogue box only

Comment: Close the webpage? You can't do that...You can't close any tab via JavaScript. You can only use window.close for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.